# How to fill a global variable without calling for it in main program flow?

Tags: c++

I'l like this piece of the library to be accessible without having to explicitly initialize it first, heres what I tried:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

struct SysInfoClass {
    DWORD granB;
    SysInfoClass() {
        SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;
        GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);
        granB = siSysInfo.dwAllocationGranularity;
    }
};

SysInfoClass SysInfo();
```

Ok, that seems fine. I expected this to create the instance of SysInfoClass before the programs main function executes so that I could just go auto x = SysInfo.granB anywhere but it does not work. I can assign SysInfo to things but I can't access any of its members, why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access"? do you get a compiler error? what's the error?

Comment: `SysInfoClass SysInfo()` is a function, not a variable - maybe that's what is causing trouble - otherwise I'm not sure what you are doing so not sure what is going wrong... Remove the parenthesis...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error.
Instead of

```
SysInfoClass SysInfo();
```

You need to write

```
SysInfoClass SysInfo;
```

The way you wrote it, the compiler thinks it's a function declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Turn the global variable into a `static` local variable in a free-standing function which returns a reference to the variable.

```
SysInfoClass& SysInfo()
{
    static SysInfoClass sys_info;
    return sys_info;
}
```

Comment: downvoted - telling the person to do something completely different than what he wants to do.

Comment: @shoosh: Well, I admit that I didn't understand what the OP's problem was. Still, the answer solves the problem and improves the code.